# Crash without log: toObject

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to map the document to a custom class but the app constantly crashes without logs.

I am still learning, so the map only contains 1 entry, called `"pin"` with value `"0"`.

This is the code:

```
public Response<User> login(LoginRequest request) {
    Task<DocumentSnapshot> task = firestore.collection(NetDatabase.Collections.USERS)
            .document(request.getDni())
            .get();

    DocumentSnapshot document = null;
    try { 
        document = Tasks.await(task); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Response<>( new Error()); 
    }

    if (document != null && document.exists()){
        User user = document.toObject(User.class); // <-- CRASH
        if (user.getPin().equals(request.getPin())){
            return new Response<>(user);
        }
    }
    return new Response<>(new Error());
}
```

And this is the `User` class:

```
public class User extends RealmObject implements NetResponse {

    private String id;
    private String pin;

    public User(){ }

    public User(String pin){
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPin() {
        return pin;
    }
}

public interface NetResponse {
    void setId(String id);
}
```

I tried to swap between `private` and `public` but the result remains the same. The `document` is retrieved correctly, it contains a single entry with values mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it.

Basically, since `Firestore` is creating the `Object`, making it `extends RealmObject` may generate some kind of conflict. After erasing it, it all works as intended.